# Adding code to a javascript module pattern from an outside file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, knockout.js, module

First of all I'm pretty new to javascript.

I have wrote a javascript plug-in that filters html records. Using Knockout.js, basically keyword/s are typed into a text box and the plug-in filters through the html records to reveal the records that contain the keyword/s.

I have wrote the javascript using the Module pattern, and would like the opportunity for the .js file to stand alone, whilst also giving the user the opportunity to change ways in which the filter works.

Here is a brief and simple overview of the structure of my .js file:

```
$(function(){
  var s,
  Filter = {

    settings:{
      //default settings
    },

    initialise: function(){
      s = this.settings;
      this.someFunction1;
      this.someFunction2;
    },

    someFunction1: function(){
      //
    },

    someFunction2: function(){
      //
    },

  }

  Filter.initialise();

});
```

As you can see, I have specified one function to be called - `initialise`. Within `initialise` I have set the variable `s` (declared at the same level as the module) to point to `settings` so that all sub functions of the module can access it.

What I want to know is, is it possible for the overriding settings to be passed via the html file that calls the .js file?

Ideally I would like there to be default settings for the plug-in, but give the user the option to specify/override certain settings unique to their need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, there's a few peculiarities in your code.

One thing is that you have `this.someFunction1;` (and one for the second function) in your `initialize` function, but that doesn't quite *do* anything. It's just a statement.

Another thing is that you declare `Filter` as an object, but you're missing `,` (commas) between the various properties.

Finally, you declare `someFunction2` twice (though I assume it's an copy/paste error?), and you're missing a semi-colon.

To find these problems you can use a JavaScript linting tool, for example [JSHint](http://jshint.com/). Try copy-pasting your question's code there and you'll see all those issues pop up.

If I fix those issues I get to this:

```
$(function(){
  var s,
  Filter = {

    settings:{
      //default settings
    },

    initialise: function(){
      s = this.settings;
    },

    someFunction1: function(){
      //
    },

    someFunction2: function(){
      //
    }

  };

  Filter.initialise();

});
```

Currently in this code, the `Filter` is only visible in the outer closure. To make it available to other bits of code you'll have to export it, either to your own namespace object or as a jQuery plugin.

The first option is possible, but will require a bit more work and assumptions about your setup. So let me stick to showing the second option. The [jQuery's plugin tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) is pretty good, but I've based the following code on [this blogpost](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/) because it's a bit more complete IMO:

```
(function($) {

    $.filter = function(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
            // default settings
        }

        var filter = this;

        filter.settings = {};

        var initialise = function() {
            filter.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            filter.element = element;
            // code goes here
        }

        // This function is *public*, just save it in a 'var' instead of setting it
        // as a property of 'plugin' to keep it private to your plugin.
        filter.someFunction1 = function() {
            // 
        }

        filter.someFunction2 = function() {
            // 
        }

        initialise();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

In this code [the jQuery `extend` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is used above to extend default settings with user provided options.

You can call your plugin in its most basic form like this:

```
var options = { filterEmptyOptions: true, showTimeZone: false, /* etc */ };
$.filter($('#myDiv'), options);
```

Additionally you could save the result of last line and call the plugin's public methods later on.

Comment: Hi. You're right, there were a few bits wrong with the code (now edited) - I just put this together as a skeletal representation of what I've actually got, so the comments were just there as substitute for my code.

Thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate your assistance. I'll have a go to see if it works.